# Undefined method for config.swagger_root for Rspec core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, rspec-rails

I have used rswag before, with exactly the same setup. But for some reason i can not run my rspec or rake rswag:specs:swaggerize; i always get the error the method 'swagger-root=' undefined. I can't find out why.

I already tried to install all the rswag files again; 
rails g rswag:api:install rswag:ui:install
RAILS_ENV=test rails g rswag:specs:install
i also tried to install rspec again.

""An error occurred while loading ./spec/integration/translations_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: config.swagger_root = Rails.root.to_s + '/swagger'

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `swagger_root=' for #""

/spec/swagger_helper.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.swagger_root = Rails.root.to_s + '/swagger'

  config.swagger_docs = {
    'v1/swagger.json' => {
      swagger: '2.0',
      info: {
        title: 'API V1',
        version: 'v1'
      },
      paths: {}
    }
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of things, this eventually seemed the answer:
changing two lines in the spec_helper file.
From this:

```
root = File.expand_path('../', File.dirname(__FILE__))
Dir[File.join(root,'lib/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

To this:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

Probably the word 'root' should not be used here..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `gem "rswag-specs"` is in the `:test` section of the Gemfile, and not just the `:development` section:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rswag-specs"
end
```